# How to Subscribe to an inner observable using mergeMap in a click handle of a button

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs, ionic4

In the "addToWishlist" function below, I am taking the result of the outer observable and concatenating it to the inner observable array and call the next method on the inner observable. I call the method "addToWishlist" on the click handler "onAddToWishlist" of a button. The button is on every item of a list of products. The problem is that I only get the product I clicked on if I click on the button twice. The first time a click I get an empty array. For example, if I have product 1, 2 and 3, If I click on product 1, I get an empty array, If I click on product 2 that's when I get product one in the array, If I again click any other product that's when product 2 also appears on the array. Please check the code below, also included an image of the application.[Product list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IgVeK.png)

```
addToWishlist(productId: string) {
      return this.getProduct(productId).pipe(mergeMap(
         product => {
            return this.wishlist.pipe(
               take(1),
               tap(wishlist => {
                  this._wishlist.next(wishlist.concat({ ...product }));
               })
            );
         }
      ));
   }

get wishlist() {
      return this._wishlist.asObservable();
}

// Click handler for the wishlist button
onAddToWishlist(productId: string) {
      this.wishlistSub = 
       this.productsService.addToWishlist(productId).subscribe(wishlist => {
         this.wishlist = wishlist;
         console.log(wishlist); 
      });
}
```

Comment: What does set wishlist look like? What is the type of _wishlist? You might want to have a look at BehaviorSubject.

Comment: you should first subscribe to your behavior subject and try to see value is appending

Comment: @Daniel. This is how a defined the _wishlist, it is the BehaviorSubject:
private products = new BehaviorSubject<Product[]>([]);
private _wishlist = new BehaviorSubject<Product[]>([]);

FanCheung. I did try to subscribe directly inside the "addToWishlist"  function and I got the same behavior as described above. The value only gets appended on the second click of the button. It seems mergeMap makes a subscription on the outer observable on the first button click, and on the second button click that's when the value is appended on the inner observable.

Comment: Have a look on this example, maybe it could help you to rethink? https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gtfgnv

Answer (score 0):

The problem ist that you don't manipulate the value within your pipe. In order to have the result right away, you also need to map to the new value you expect when subscribing.

```
   addToWishlist(productId: string) {
      return this.getProduct(productId).pipe(mergeMap(
         product => {
            return this.wishlist.pipe(
               take(1),
               map(wishlist => wishlist.concat({ ...product })),
               tap(wishlist => this._wishlist.next(wishlist)),
            );
         }
      ));
   }
```